# 18.04 Why's my fan always ON when plugged into a power source?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, acer, fan, tlp

I bought a brand new laptop a week ago ([Acer Nitro 5 AN515 54](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NH.Q5AEK.009)) and installed Ubuntu 18.04. The fan is running really loud when on AC (everything is ok when changing it back to battery only). I installed [lm-sensors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) and the temperature is varying from 35-40 Celsius. GPU temperature is around 33-40 too, so it's not about the workload. Even when just running Mozilla and browsing, the fan starts and doesn't stop until I change the power source to battery only. I've tried installing [tlp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/tlp.8.html) and everything stays the same (fan normal on bat but loud on AC). I tried with [cpufreq](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cpufreq-set.1.html) and other tools too, tried tracking the CPUs in a System monitor but no spikes. Laptop is not overheating at all but the fan stays loud and it's annoying. Here are my specs:

[Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZspY9.png).

What should I do? What is causing this? I have been trying to figure it out for a week but nothing, I've read through some (ALL) similar questions but nothing. As shown on the picture, NVIDIA is selected in Prime profile (and my driver is up to date, [nvidia-driver-435](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/nvidia-driver-435) proprietary, tested). Choosing Intel in the [Prime](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu) profile does nothing (fan is still loud and my 2nd monitor is not detected above all). No options for the fan in the BIOS also. I know this is not the best laptop, but the specs aren't that bad plus it's brand new. At the moment of writing this post my CPU temperatures are between 33-37 (no spikes in the system monitor), GPU 34, Memory 4.5 GiB of 15.5 (29.6%) and the fan is loud. I plug it out and the fan stops in 5-10 seconds. I'm sorry if I'm writing too many details but I just want some advice cause I'm getting desperate :O

I've tried with the default config of tlp but nothing, change it to this [tlp-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ke7d.png) but nothing!!! Am I missing something?

If you need any more data about the laptop or anything else, please let me know.